# SMB office fair share of bandwith

Tags: router, broadband, soho

We're 2-3 persons working in a remote office sharing a DSL connection with around 10Mbit down and 1Mbit up speed. The problem is that if one of us starts a big download or something, the other users essentially loses access to RDP sessions and what not.

I'm not too well versed in the world of SOHO routers and network equipment, so I'm wondering if anyone knows if there's a router product or "something" we can implement to establish a fair share of internet bandwith?

Comment: You need to investigate QoS and look to implement QoS for services that are affected by SMB traffic like HTTP, HTTPS, RDP, etc. This will then make these protocols priority over SMB.

Answer (score 0):

QoS (Quality of Service) is what you are looking for.  On your gateway (VPN/ADSL router) you should be able to prioritise traffic.

If you prioritise other traffic (RDP on port 3389, Web on 80/443, DNS on 53, Email on 25/143/110 for smtp/imap/pop, 389 for LDAP and Active directory etc) then the priority of traffic on SMB will become lower and will essentially get whatevers leftover after these other services have had their share of your bandwidth.

As for how you do this specifically on your setup - we sould need mroe information on your setup (router makes & models, VPN type etc..)